# issue with video_player and channel getting null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i got a issue that i try understand how i can fix this
i get this error message about the **Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)**
i have try look into but i have no idea why or how it hapending the full message within the post

i try understand what the origin this happened i try clean the build folder via flutter clean this happend
i try run build runner it may missing something nope i got no idea what seem to be the issue here

```
    [GETX] REPLACE ROUTE /splash
    [GETX] NEW ROUTE /login
    I/flutter (17459): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    I/flutter (17459): │ #0   LoggerService.info
    package:demo_ecom/…/utils/logger_service.dart:19
    I/flutter (17459): │ #1   _LoginScreenState.initState
    package:demo_ecom/…/login/login_screen.dart:32
    I/flutter (17459): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
    I/flutter (17459): │  Load Login Screen
    I/flutter (17459): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    E/flutter (17459): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
    E/flutter (17459): #0      VideoPlayerApi.initialize
    package:video_player_platform_interface/messages.dart:156
    E/flutter (17459): <asynchronous suspension>
    E/flutter (17459):
    E/flutter (17459): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
    E/flutter (17459): #0      VideoPlayerApi.create
    package:video_player_platform_interface/messages.dart:181
    E/flutter (17459): <asynchronous suspension>
    E/flutter (17459): #1      MethodChannelVideoPlayer.create
    package:video_player_platform_interface/method_channel_video_player.dart:47
    E/flutter (17459): <asynchronous suspension>
    E/flutter (17459): #2      VideoPlayerController.initialize
    package:video_player/video_player.dart:308
    E/flutter (17459): <asynchronous suspension>
    E/flutter (17459):
    Lost connection to device.
```

the file that play this vid as follow

```
    import 'dart:async';

    import 'package:demo_ecom/common/utils/logger_service.dart';
    import 'package:demo_ecom/widgets/login/login_buttons.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
    import 'package:demo_ecom/generated/l10n.dart';

    import 'login_form.dart';

    class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const LoginScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
    }

    class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
      final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      VideoPlayerController _controller;
      bool _visible = false;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();

        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        ]);
        LoggerService().info('Load Login Screen');
        _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/media/login-vid.mp4');
        _controller.initialize().then((_) {
          _controller.setLooping(true);
          Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.play();
              _visible = true;
            });
          });
        });
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        if (_controller != null) {
          _controller.dispose();
          _controller = null;
        }
      }

      Widget _getVideoBackground() {
        return AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
        );
      }

      Widget _getBackgroundColor() {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.black.withAlpha(120),
        );
      }

      Widget _getContent(BuildContext context) {
        final splogen_1 = S.of(context).login_slogen;
        final splogen_2 = S.of(context).login_slogen2;
        return Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(
                height: 40.0,
              ),
              const Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/media/logo.jpg'),
                width: 150.0,
              ),
              Text(
                splogen_1,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 40.0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  splogen_2,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
              LoginForm(),
              LoginButtons()
            ],
          ),
        );
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _getVideoBackground(),
                  _getBackgroundColor(),
                  _getContent(context),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

the pubspec  as follow

```
    name: demo_ecom
    description: Demo Ecom App

    # The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
    # pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
    publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

    # The following defines the version and build number for your application.
    # A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
    # followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
    # Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
    # build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
    # In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
    # Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
    # In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
    # Read more about iOS versioning at
    # https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
    version: 1.0.0+2

    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      flutter_localizations:
        sdk: flutter

      # Service locator
      provider: ^5.0.0

      # Connectivity
      data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
      # Logging
      logger: ^1.0.0
      # Json
      json_annotation: ^4.0.1

      # firebase
      firebase_core: ^0.7.0
      firebase_remote_config: "^0.6.0"
      firebase_auth: "^0.20.1"
      firebase_crashlytics: ^0.4.0+1

      #auth social
      google_sign_in: "^4.5.1"
      flutter_facebook_auth: "^1.0.0"
      # localization
      intl: ^0.17.0
      # ui tools
      flutter_password_strength: ^0.1.6
      flutter_signin_button: ^1.1.0
      animations: ^2.0.0
      pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.4
      get: ^3.26.0
      flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.0
      responsive_framework: ^0.1.0
      animated_text_kit: ^4.1.0
      flutter_spinkit: "^5.0.0"
      convex_bottom_bar: ^3.0.0
      introduction_screen: ^2.0.0
      flash: ^1.5.1
      material_floating_search_bar: ^0.3.3
      video_player: ^2.0.0
      chewie: ^1.0.0
      # ui icons

      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
      font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
      flutter_icons: ^1.1.0

      # misc tools
      validators: ^2.0.1
      dio: ^3.0.10
      pretty_dio_logger: ^1.1.1
      jiffy: ^4.0.0
      equatable: ^2.0.0
      meta: ^1.3.0
      stack_trace: ^1.10.0
      shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
      async: ^2.5.0
    # override requirement that conflict will rise if removed
    dependency_overrides:
      analyzer: ^1.3.0
      yaml: ^3.1.0
      intl: ^0.17.0
      dart_style: ^2.0.0
      args: ^2.0.0
      glob: ^2.0.0
      source_gen: ^1.0.0
      logging: ^1.0.1
      convert: ^3.0.0
      crypto: ^3.0.0
      vin_decoder: ^0.1.3
      json_annotation: ^4.0.1
      font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
    dev_dependencies:
      # add build runner if not already added
      build_runner: ^1.12.2
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
      # Linting
      lint: ^1.5.3

      # Json
      json_serializable: ^4.1.0

      # misc tools
      mockito: ^5.0.2
      flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
      environment_config: ^2.2.5
      flutter_rename_app: ^1.0.0
    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:
      # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
      # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
      # the material Icons class.
      uses-material-design: true
      assets:
        - assets/fonts/
        - assets/media/
        - assets/icons/
      # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

      # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

      # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
      # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
      # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
      # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
      # example:
      # fonts:
      #   - family: Schyler
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
      #         style: italic
      #   - family: Trajan Pro
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
      #         weight: 700
      #
      # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
      # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-package

      # To hide the notification bar, use the fullscreen parameter.  Has no affect in web since web
      # has no notification bar.  Defaults to false.
      # NOTE: Unlike Android, iOS will not automatically show the notification bar when the app loads.
      #       To show the notification bar, add the following code to your Flutter app:
      #       WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      #       SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom, SystemUiOverlay.top]);
      #fullscreen: true

      # If you have changed the name(s) of your info.plist file(s), you can specify the filename(s)
      # with the info_plist_files parameter.  Remove only the # characters in the three lines below,
      # do not remove any spaces:
      #info_plist_files:
      #  - 'ios/Runner/Info-Debug.plist'
      #  - 'ios/Runner/Info-Release.plist'
    flutter_intl:
      enabled: true
      localizely:
        project_id: c4305176-c927-4336-80bd-7bbc91f25b3d
    flutter_icons:
      image_path: 'assets/assets/icons/app_icon.png'
      android: true
      ios: true

    flutter_rename_app:
      application_name: Demo Ecom
      dart_package_name: demo_ecom
      application_id: com.wolberg.pro.demo
      bundle_id: com.wolberg.pro.demo
      android_package_name: com.wolberg.pro.demo
    targets:
      $default:
        builders:
          injectable_generator:injectable_builder:
            options:
              auto_register: true
              # auto registers any class with a name matches the given pattern
              class_name_pattern:
                "Service$|Repository$"
                # auto registers any class inside a file with a
              # name matches the given pattern
              file_name_pattern: "_service$|_repository$"
    #flutter pub run flutter_rename_app
```

i got no idea what i can do not sure what i did here wrong  thanks for the helpers